# "Open Existing Android Studio Project" option does not work in freshly installed Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to open an existing Android Studio project in a freshly installed Android Studio in a new PC. However, when I used the "**Open an existing Android Studio project**" option, a windows was popped up to ask me to set up the Gradle home.

[image]

This confuses me, because Android Studio should use the gradle wrapper to download the correct version of Gradle. But the option "**Use default gradle wrapper**" wasn't selectable.

I'm sure this project can be opened in my old computer via "**Open an existing Android Studio project**" without problems.

Do I need to download the Gradle manually here? Or is there some other way I can open my project?

**Note**: I'm not migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Thanks!!

Comment: Same for me. Gave up on importing anything into that Android Studio some months ago. Creation of new project with same package name and copy the source - is much faster and less stress, trust me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open an existing project using "**Import project**" option.

Comment: i haven't 50 reputation to comment